# Loading chemmacros with check-declarations option set for expl3 raises compile error

Tags: chemmacros

Loading `chemmacros` raises compile error `! LaTeX error: "kernel/non-declared-variable"!!` if `expl3` is loaded with the `[check-declarations]` option.

```
\documentclass{article} 
% RN. 8 August 2018 
%======================= 
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{chemmacros} 
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
   Hi there!    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a bug report to the chemmacros author.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would I do this through the TeX.SE using an established format, or should I just informally address myself to the package author (Clemens Niederberger) via email?

Comment: How to report a bug for a package is normally written in the documentation. You can ask here if you are unsure if something is a bug or which package is reponsable, but in such a clear case tex.sx is not the right place, it is not an issue tracker.

Comment: How about https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros/issues?

Comment: The undeclared variable is used in `chemformula`, not in `chemmacros`. See https://github.com/cgnieder/chemformula/issues/9

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report

Comment: While some package authors frequent this site, not all do, and those who do might not be able to read all questions and answers about their packages. So if you find a bug, you should definitely contact the author directly via the channels mentioned in the documentation. Many maintainers have a e-mail address others prefer a bug report via GitHub, GitLab or another development platform.

Comment: @moewe The small question remains how users are alerted when a fix has been provided by the package author - daily package update I suppose.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth There is the CTAN mailing list (or comp.text.tex) if you want to know about package releases, but small updates may not be advertised there. People will always have to decide for themselves if and when they want to update. Posting bug reports here in addition to a proper bug report has little additional value. It may encourage people not to file a real bug report, because bugs seem to be reported on this site. It does not make for exiting or interesting questions if the answer is just, bug reported, wait for update x.y.z. Plus these questions lose relevance after a while...

Comment: ... Most importantly, I don't think this platform is good for announcements of the form "package X has a bug, update to version y.z". For hot topics there are thousands of questions on this site, it is not reasonable to go through all of them to find out whether or not I should update.

Comment: https://github.com/cgnieder/chemformula/issues/9#event-2656068146